# RobotFramework with Python, I see an error message : Keyword 'SeleniumLibrary.Create Webdriver' expected 1 to 3 non-named arguments, got 0

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I have written a first and simple code in python using Robot Framework.
I am opening up a URL and passing Login Id and Password.

When I run the code I see an error message : Keyword 'SeleniumLibrary.Create Webdriver' expected 1 to 3 non-named arguments, got 0.

Below is my code :

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***


*** Test Cases ***

LoginTest
    create webdriver    chrome executable_path="/users/drivers/chromedriver"

    open browser    https://www.nopcommerce.com/    chrome
    click link  xpath://*[@id="en-page"]/body/div[6]/header/div/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a/span[1
    click link  xpath://*[@id="en-page"]/body/div[6]/header/div/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a
    input text  id:Email ABC
    input text  id:Password 123
    click element   class:btn blue-button
    close browser

*** Keywords ***
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two or more spaces between `chrome` and `executable_path=...`

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to add your browser's web-driver file's path in environment variables.

OR

Simply you can copy the web-driver file into your Python installation inside Python>>Scripts folder and it will be in the path automatically.

After that Create webdriver keyword is not required.